# KendoUI combo box loading the data faster

Tags: postgresql, kendo-ui, ado.net

I can display my data in kendoUI combobox with db integration(PostgresSQL) but my combo box is performing 1-2 seconds slower than i expected when i click on dropdown arrow. Can anyone help me out how to load the data faster when i click on my dropdown of combobox?

Comment: Can you give us your code to look at and what you want?

Comment: Do have you autoBind set to false? If so, the data for the widget is only retrieved when it is opened which would potentially cause a visible delay. Show your code, particularly the html/javascript rather than the server.

Comment: If you could let me know how and where to post my code here that would be helpful.

Comment: I tried putting autobind true also but did not bring any difference

Comment: I have pasted the code below, please let me know what am i missing in the code @MikeTung

Comment: Setting it to autobind true also did not work. Please let me know what else changes can we make@NigeIK

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-sm-5  col-xs-10">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center col-xs-3"><h4>MPID</h4></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5  col-xs-9">
                        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                        .Name("cmbBrokers")
                            .DataTextField("MPID")
                            .DataValueField("MPID")
                            .Placeholder("--")
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
                            .Events(e => { e.Change("onClientSelect"); })
                            .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
                            .DataSource(source =>
                            {
                                source.Read(read =>
                                {
                                    read.Action("GetBrokers", "BrokerMapping");
                                }).ServerFiltering(false);
                            })
                                .HeaderTemplate("<div class=\"dropdown-header \">" +
                    "<span>MPID</span>" +
                    "<span>Name</span>" +
                    "<span>NSCCID</span>" +
                "</div>")
      .FooterTemplate("Total <strong>#: instance.dataSource.total() #</strong> items found")
      .Template("<div class=\"dropdown\"><span> #:data.MPID# </span><span>#: data.CompanyName #</span>" + "<span>#: data.NSCCID #</span></div>")
                        )
                    </div>

**Here is my javascript**
<script>
function searchData(searchText) {      
    var grid = $("#brokersGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataSource = grid.dataSource;

    dataSource.filter({
        logic: "or",
        filters: [{
            "field": "MPID",
            "operator": "startswith",
            "value": searchText
        },
            {
                field: "CompanyName",
                operator: "startswith",
                value: searchText
            },
            {
                field: "NSCCID",
                operator: "startswith",
                value: searchText
            }]
    });
}
function onClientSelect(e) {
    var searchText = this.value();
    document.getElementById("txtSearch").value = "";
    searchData(searchText);
}
function brokersGridDataBound(e) {
    var combo = $("#cmbBrokers").data("kendoComboBox");      
    combo.dataSource.read();
}
```

Comment: Above is my code for kendoUI combo box with javascript included Please let me know if i am missing anything to load data faster.